# How to add GDPR consent dialog in app and GDPR related confusions

Tags: android, ios, app-store

I have apps on AppStore and play store. I want to clear some points regarding GDPR. Hopefully, I will get the help from this forum.

Below are some of my confusions.

1) If I remove my apps from EU countries (remove from EU countries app store and play store) then it is ok for me not to put consent dialog in my apps? And what happened if EU user goes into US market and download my app and found no consent dialog?

2) If I place consent box then I have to show consent dialog to all the users? Because without getting consent, I'm not allowed to get the country of the user. If I'm wrong please correct me.

3) My apps monetization is based on 4 networks (admob,chartboost,unityads,vungle). Do i have to place 4 consent dialogs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1) If I remove my apps from EU countries (remove from EU countries app store and play store) then it is ok for me not to put consent dialog in my apps?**

=> YES,it's ok. no need for showing consent dialog.

**1.1) there no problem if the user changes store fro EU-country to the US and then download my app?**

=> Then it's user that belong to US,so it not cause any issue because GDPR for EU-Country.

**2) If I place consent box then I have to show consent dialog to all the users? Because without getting consent, I'm not allowed to get the country of the user. If I'm wrong please correct me.**

=> You need to show the dialog if user is belong to European Union only.for other country it's not needed.

For this you have to use some trick for that

**Solution:**

> You have to get the IP address of user then using
>   https://github.com/seventhmoon/IpApi-retrofit you can identify user
>   belong to European Union or not?
>
> it belong to European Union
>   If YES
>         **show the consent dialog**
>   else
>
> **not need to for consent dialog**

**3) My apps monetization is based on 4 networks (admob,chartboost,unityads,vungle). Do i have to place 4 consent dialogs?**

=> No,you just need to show a single consent dialog. if user agree store that value(in SharedPref) for future reference and pass it with all other network.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
For 1, there no problem if the user changes store fro EU-country to the US and then download my app?
For 2, Am I allowed to get the IP without consent?

Comment: i have updated the answer for 1. for 2 yes it can because `he GDPR refers to sensitive personal data as "special categories of personal data which uniqely identify a person." This will include genetic data and biometric data.`

Answer (score 1):

Use [Google Consent SDK](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent) to check if user is in European Economic Area (EEA).

In `build.gradle` add:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.6'
```

Use `ConsentInformation.getInstance(context).requestConsentInfoUpdate( ... )` as [described in the docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent#update_consent_status).

Then use

```
ConsentInformation.getInstance(context).isRequestLocationInEeaOrUnknown()
```

If function returns `true` apply GDPR rules to your app (e.g. show consent dialog). You need to show consent dialog once, but if you add another network you need to get consent again. You may store consent version the user has accepted and compare with current one.

Comment: This requires  you to have AdMob and Admob Publisher ID.

Comment: @SlimC., mayby my answer is not useful in your case, but is it not relevant to the question above? Is it "egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect"? Maybe you should post another question with your specific requirements mentioned.

Comment: users could choice options which would result in 0 ads, its an issue with admob consent lib, if they disable storage consent, no ads are shown, dont use this lib