# How User Messaging Platform (UMP) SDK for IOS Maui

Tags: c#, ios, .net, admob, maui

I found 1 documentation to implement UMP for IOS, because AdMob asked me, I succeeded for Android, but for IOS I found that https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/issues/931 , except I have errors, the compiler cannot find using Google.MobileAds.Consent;, and ConsentInformation.
I installed (Xamarin.Google.iOS.UserMessagingPlatform, Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds and Xamarin.Google.UserMessagingPlatform)

```
using Foundation;
using Google.MobileAds;
using UIKit;
using Google.MobileAds.Consent;

namespace Orbis.Mobile;

[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : MauiUIApplicationDelegate
{
    protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() => MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();

    public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
    {
        AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(url);
        return base.OpenUrl(app, url, options);
    }

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        MobileAds.SharedInstance.Start(CompletionHandler);

        //MobileAds.Configure("<YOUR_APP_ID>");

        ConsentInformation.SharedInstance.RequestConsentInfoUpdate(new string[] { "pub-0[1](https://cookieinformation.com/resources/blog/is-your-mobile-app-gdpr-compliant/)[2](https://www.appknox.com/resources/guides/make-your-mobile-app-compliant-to-gdpr)[3](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10113207?hl=en)[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50486708/how-to-add-gdpr-consent-dialog-in-app-and-gdpr-related-confusions)56789012345" }, (error) =>
        {
            if (error == null)
            {
                if (ConsentInformation.SharedInstance.IsRequestLocationInEeaOrUnknown)
                {
                    ConsentForm consentForm = new ConsentForm();
                    consentForm.Load((loadError) =>
                    {
                        if (loadError == null)
                        {
                            consentForm.Show((dismissError, userPrefersAdFree) =>
                            {
                                if (dismissError == null)
                                {
                                    switch (ConsentInformation.SharedInstance.ConsentStatus)
                                    {
                                        case ConsentStatus.NonPersonalized:
                                            break;
                                        case ConsentStatus.Personalized:
                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });


        return base.FinishedLaunching(application, launchOptions);
    }
    private void CompletionHandler(InitializationStatus status) { }
}
```